# bytes.Split separator as []byte("...")

Tags: string, types, byte, go

In [bytes_test.go](http://golang.org/src/pkg/bytes/bytes_test.go) I see:

```
 a := Split([]byte(tt.s), []byte(tt.sep), tt.n)
```

where tt.s and tt.sep are strings. But when I try to do

```
 a := bytes.Split([]byte("test"), []byte("e"), 0)
```

I get:

```
 cannot convert "test" (type ideal string) to type []uint8 in conversion
 cannot convert "e" (type ideal string) to type []uint8 in conversion
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is valid code using the latest release -- [release.2010-03-04](http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/msg/ebcf609a8bbb5560) -- which includes, amongst other things, this change: "There is one language change: the ability to convert a string to []byte or []int.  This deprecates the strings.Bytes and strings.Runes functions."

```
package main

import ("bytes"; "fmt")

func main() {
    a := bytes.Split([]byte("test"), []byte("e"), 0)
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Update to a current release of Go: [Installing Go : Keeping up with releases](http://golang.org/doc/install.html#tmp_101).

Comment: Thanks! It seems I just got confused with my PATH and was using older version (while having new).